# Grails - How to invoke a servlet while running a test case?

Tags: grails

I have a servlet configured in my web.xml file which is configured as

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ConfigFileLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.adapter.messaging.ConfigFileLoader</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This is a part of some legacy java code that is integrated with my grails application. How can I ensure that I run this before I execute my test case?

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests do not start and run a servlet container. If you need a servlet container to be used during testing then you have to use an Integration test.

Without knowing what your servlet does I can't suggest any alternatives other than the above proper approach.